# Re render a component on object value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know how to make my component update when the value of my object changes. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";


const OccupationZone = ({ polygon }) => {
return (
 <div>
   <h1>Taux d'occupation</h1>
   {polygon.map(poly => {
     if (poly.type == "occupation") {
       console.log(poly);
       return (
         <div key={poly._leaflet_id}>
         <span>
           {poly.label} : {poly.occupationPercentage}
         </span>
       </div>
       );
     }
   })}
 </div>
);
};

export default OccupationZone;
```

I'm receiving polygon as props. This is an array of objects. When I add a new polygon, the return does its job and add the new one to the list with the map, and his name poly.label is displaying correctly.

In another component, I change the value of occupationPercentage, but when it's changed, I can see the new value in the console.log(poly), but the span with poly.occupationPercentage does not update and stay at his default value.

[Before occupationPercentage change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8bcv.png)

[After occupationPercentage change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIYUA.png)

Comment: My bad, I edited my code, that was a mistake when a wrote the post

Comment: Are you using state in the parent component? If you already use state in the parent, could you please share the main functionality of the parent that change the value?

Comment: The polygon array is comming from a Redux state

Comment: Any codesandbox with working example?

Comment: I tried your code with a simple useState to store the polygon array and it works correctly and displays any change of occupationPercentage

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that occupationPercentage is not stored in redux but calculated somewhere else and added to each polygon before being sent as a props to OccupationZone

Comment: @HermitCrab Yes, that's how it's done in my code

Comment: That's why it is not updated then, that's perfectly normal. It will be rendered the first time but won't be updated because occupationPercentage doesn't come from redux

Comment: Could you calculate this occupationPercentage  directly inside your map function? That will solve the problem

Comment: I found a solution, thank's for guiding me in the right direction :)